# Persisting two entities that refer to one

Tags: hibernate, jpa

[image]

I have three entities as shown in the image.

I am trying to persist the objects as shown in this pseudo code

```
EA = new EA
EB = new EB
EC = new EC
EB.link(EA)
EC.link(EA)
persist(EB)
persist(EC)
```

When persisting Entity B, Entity A get persisted but then Entity C fails to persist with the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object is an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before merging:
```

I control entity C. I would not like to change anything in Entities A and B. How can I get all these entities to be persisted?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work:

```
EA = new EA
EB = new EB
EC = new EC
EB.link(EA)
persist(EB)
EC.link(EB.getEA())
persist(EC)
```

Comment: Although I have not tried it yet, seems it is going to work. The only issue is that in the real life situation that I am facing, there is a list of EA and to get a certain one I need an ID. EB.getEA(id). The problem is an ID of EA get generated only after the entity is persisted I suppose.  So I cannot save the id's of EA in EC to get them later ...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I had to change the model for it to work nicely.

the pseudo-code is

```
EA=new EA
EB=new EB
EC=new EC
EB.link(EA)
EB.link(EC)
persist(EB)
```